# Transformation Performance XML>XSL>XML vs XML>JAXB>XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb

I have a case with an xml as input and a different xml as output :
I have the choice between using XSL and Unmarshalling marshalling through JAXB.
Performance wise, is there any real difference ?

Comment: A key decision is whether you are able to compile and cache your XSL stylesheet as a `Template`. Another question is whether you use an XSLT interpreter (e.g. Xalan) or a compiler (e.g. XSLTC). If you have to parse your XSL stylesheet every time, it'll need significantly more time. If you use an XSLT compiler and are able to cache the result, I'd go for XSLT... but I do not have any metrics on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, programmer performance is usually much more important than machine performance. A good fast server costs less than employing a programmer for a day. So are you asking the right question?

Secondly, if the transformation is simple then in both cases the cost will be dominated by parsing and serialization costs, and there is no reason why these should differ in the two cases. If the transformation is more complex, then its performance depends in practice on the skills of the person writing the code, so it comes back to a programming question again.

I would say that the real difference between using JAXB and using XSLT will be that the XSLT solution is likely to be fewer lines of code, and less sensitive to schema change.

Comment: Ok so with the same programmer there is not much difference between the two, right ?

Comment: @redben: In case there is just one programmer (and he doesn't know or prefer XSLT) your question loses any meaning. XSLT is a language especially designed for XML transformations, therefore its use for this task has definite benefits compared to using other languages. This means that *all other conditions equal* it is reasonable to prefer XSLT for the task. As for performance, it has been shown that it depends much more on the algorithm used than on the choice of programming language -- read Jon Bentley. And to quote Donald Knut, "*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*"